# Cannot get the dynamically generated textviews values

Tags: android

I'm not getting the values of dynamically generated TextViews.

My code is,

```
public class Stock_check_fragment extends Fragment {
    private AutoCompleteTextView auto;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> values;
    LinearLayout ly;
    int i = 0;
    List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    Button btn;
    EditText qty;
    Button next;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.stock_check, container, false);

        ly = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

        auto = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);

        values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("Kasun");
        values.add("KasunW");
        values.add("Sinmki");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, values);

        auto.setThreshold(1);
        auto.setAdapter(adapter);

        auto.setOnItemClickListener(autoItemSelectedListner);
        next.setOnClickListener(o1);

        return rootView;

    }

    private OnItemClickListener autoItemSelectedListner = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Add_text(auto.getText().toString());
        }
    };

    public void Add_text(String value) {

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.setId(i);

        TextView product = new TextView(getActivity());
        product.setText(value);
        ll.addView(product);

        qty = new EditText(getActivity());
        qty.setText(i + "");
        qty.setId(i);
        qty.setWidth(120);

        ll.addView(qty);

        Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
        ll.addView(btn);
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
      ly.addView(ll);
        i++;

    }



    OnClickListener o1 = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup parentView = ly;

            for (int i = 0; i < ly.getChildCount(); i++) {
                LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) ly.getChildAt(i);
                ViewGroup child_view = l;

                for (int j = 0; j < child_view.getChildCount(); j++) {
                    View childView = parentView.getChildAt(i);


                     if(childView instanceof TextView){

                        TextView t = (TextView) childView;
                Log.i("VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV", t.getText().toString());

                     }

                }

            }
        }
    };

}
```

Here i used code to generate textviews ,EditText and Button dynamically.It works fine but i need to take all the values in textviews  when i click a button but it does not work.Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the parentView's children twice.

```
View childView = parentView.getChildAt(i);
```

Should be

```
View childview = child_view.getChildAt(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int j = 0; j < child_view.getChildCount(); j++) {
                    View childView = parentView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);

                        TextView t = (TextView) childView;
                Log.i("VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV", t.getText().toString());


                }
```